# JTable - Disallow selection and focusing of some cells while allowing others to be selected or focused

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, selection

I'm looking for a way to disallow the selection or focusing of some cells (neither a complete column or row) in a JTable.

For example: I have a very tiny table with 2 rows and 2 columns and i only want the cells (0,0) and (1,1) to be selectable and focusable, while the cells (1,0) and (0,1) can not be selected or focused.

Does someone know how to achieve this behavior? So far i only found the way to implement a custom ListSelectionModel. But it only works for columns or rows (two different models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding `JTable`'s `changeSelection` method with you custom constraints and you'll likely need to disable editing via overriding `isCellEditable` too. E.g.:

```
final JTable table = new JTable( data, columnNames ) {
    @Override
    public void changeSelection( int row, int col, boolean toggle, boolean expand ) {
        if( ( row + col )%2 == 0) { // here you set your own rules
            super.changeSelection( row, col, toggle, expand );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable( int row, int col ) {
        return false; // disabling editing separately
    }
};
```